# How to run webdriver tests in Selenium Grid linux and firefox

Tags: webdriver, selenium-grid

How to run webdriver tests in Selenium Grid linux and firefox. After setting up the selenium Grid and registering the node with the hub when i try to run the below code throws class not found error, any thoughts.

```
    URL server = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");

    System.out.println("Connecting to " + server);

    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(server, capabilities);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satish, check the error in stack trace. It says

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.tests.RemoteTest`

This is NOT a selenium exception. Your class file **RemoteTest** is not in the classpath.You need to set it in the classpath.

Comment: A.J Thanks, I should have looked more closely there was another class with the same name which caused the issue. Works like charm

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
```

I assume Firefox is installed correctly and your node has a matching firefox instance?
Could you post your config files?

Comment: Thanks for the response tried the DesiredCapabilities.firefox() still same error. Unable to post the complete config hence posted in the blog. Please find the link for the same. http://satishjohn.wordpress.com/webdriver-grid-config-and-error/

Comment: seems similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910488/selenium-server-grid2-start-problem-noclassdeffounderror-exception). Are you usinge the selenium-server-standalone jar?